# Is there any way to take the images/snapshots of hadoop HDInsight nodes and use them for the cluster creation?

Tags: azure, hadoop, cluster-computing, snapshot, azure-hdinsight

I want to take an image/snapshot of my HDInsight hadoop cluster, since I have configured drivers and some utilities on  my nodes. How can I take snapshot and use it for the cluster creation to replicate the same configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no option to take image/snapshots of the HDInsight clusters.

If your cluster is active, you will incur cost. To stop incurring charges, the recommended approach is to delete the cluster when not in use. In order to achieve this you may try: You may try this using Azure PowerShell and Automation.
For more details, refer “Automate provisioning of HDInsight [Clusters with PowerShell and Azure Automation”.](http://www.datamic.net/blog/automate-provisioning-hdinsight-clusters-with-powershell-and-azure-automation)

You may refer the documentation Create [Hadoop clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-create-linux-clusters-arm-templates) in HDInsight by using Resource Manager templates for more details.